# Context-free string that satisfies constraint?

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

I'm not sure on how to come up with a string that is in terms of $p$ for

$ a^ib^jc^k$  where $ i+j = k^2$

Where $p$ is the pumping length. I can't seem to find anything in terms of $p$ that satisifies the constraint. Any ideas or sugeestions are appreciated!

Comment: What is $p$? A property to define the language? A string length involving the pumping lemma?

Comment: Sorry, $p$ is the pumping length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to define a string that has exactly length $p$. It only has to have length at least $p$. So $(i,j,k) = (2p^2,2p^2,2p)$ so that $2p^2+2p^2 = (2p)^2$ for a string of length $4p^2+2p$ would be OK.

Comment: ugh thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for to get started. Spent all night trying to figure something out in terms of $p$.

Comment: Hendrik, may I ask how you came about the answer?

Comment: It was just a simple solution that satisfied the condition: $k^2$ should be a square that I wanted to divide in two, so $k$ should be divisible by 2. (I did not try to solve the pumping part which is next in the argument.)